# supervisord: php5-fpm exited too quickly

Tags: nginx, supervisord

I'm using supervisord running in my Docker container (`/usr/bin/supervisord -n`).

php5-fpm supervisord config looks like:

```
[program:php5-fpm]
command=/usr/sbin/php5-fpm -c /etc/php5/fpm
```

When I start the php5-fpm with supervisord I get `php5-fpm: ERROR (abnormal termination)` and it is listed as `php5-fpm FATAL Exited too quickly (process log may have details)`. There is no log data.

As you can see I have that problem with some other processes as well:
[image]

But it is running. I cannot use any supervisord commands for the `FATAL` tasks. Anyone an idea how to get it running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since processes managed by supervisord must not run in daemonize mode you have to start the fpm like `command=/usr/sbin/php5-fpm --nodaemonize -c /etc/php5/fpm`